# Is there a way to convert ContentControl to this

Tags: c#, this, contentcontrol

[MessageBoxEx](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5290638/Customizable-WPF-MessageBox)

I trying to implement XAML into CS. It succeeded but only 1 thing I can't solve and that is:
Convert this to ContentControl.

```
            object parent = this;
        MessageBoxEx.SetParentWindow(this);
```

The parent windows must be set otherwise I get a null reference.

Can somebody help me out?

Found the solution

```
public void InitMessageBox()
    {
        // Create the ElementHost control for hosting the
        // WPF UserControl.
        ContentControl host = new ContentControl();

        host.DataContext = this;
        //host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        // Create the WPF UserControl.
        MessageBoxEx uc =
            new MessageBoxEx();

        // Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's
        // Child property.
        //host.Parent = this;
        //host.Child = uc;

        // Add the ElementHost control to the form's
        // collection of child controls.
        //this.Controls.Add(host);

        // p = (ContentControl) this;
        MessageBoxEx.SetParentWindow(host);
        MessageBoxEx.SetMessageForeground(Colors.White);
        MessageBoxEx.SetMessageBackground(Colors.Black);
        MessageBoxEx.SetButtonBackground(MessageBoxEx.ColorFromString("#333333"));
        MessageBoxEx.SetButtonTemplateName("AefCustomButton");
        MessageBoxEx.SetMaxFormWidth(600);
        MessageBoxEx.SetErrorDelegate(new ErrorMsgDelegate());
        // if you want to make the MessageBoxEx silent when you use icons, uncomment the next line
        //MessageBoxEx.SetAsSilent(true);
    }
```

Comment: I need a bit more code I think.  Is `this` derived from `Window`?  You set `parent` to `this` - why?  Did you look at the example?

Comment: I've look at the example and it needs windows in the class but if I derive from Windows the form designer does not work anymore. The parent was this in the method and tryed to set ContentControl via a cast to ContenControl parent = (ContentControl) this; But get an Ilegal cast. Is there a way to tranform this to contentcontrol.

Comment: Are you creating a WPF app or a Windows Forms App?

Comment: A windows Forms App. The XAML source is from codeproject and is in the link in the message. I must look how I can post more code lines here.

Answer (score -1):

I have not done this but you must follow a special procedure to use a WPF control with Windows Forms.  Please see this link: [Use WPF controls in Windows Forms apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-wpf-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Hi @Jeff, I don't know how to post code here in a comments. Maybe Answer Your Question?

Answer (score -1):

I've some code found:

```
        public void InitMessageBox()
    {
        // Create the ElementHost control for hosting the
        // WPF UserControl.
        ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
        host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        // Create the WPF UserControl.
        MsgBoxEx.MessageBoxEx uc =
            new MsgBoxEx.MessageBoxEx();

        // Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's
        // Child property.
        host.Parent = this;
        host.Child = uc; // Error

        // Add the ElementHost control to the form's
        // collection of child controls.
        this.Controls.Add(host); // host = error

        // p = (ContentControl) this;
        MessageBoxEx.SetParentWindow(uc);
        MessageBoxEx.SetMessageForeground(Colors.White);
        MessageBoxEx.SetMessageBackground(Colors.Black);
        MessageBoxEx.SetButtonBackground(MessageBoxEx.ColorFromString("#333333"));
        MessageBoxEx.SetButtonTemplateName("AefCustomButton");
        MessageBoxEx.SetMaxFormWidth(600);
        MessageBoxEx.SetErrorDelegate(new ErrorMsgDelegate());
        // if you want to make the MessageBoxEx silent when you use icons, uncomment the next line
        //MessageBoxEx.SetAsSilent(true);
    }
```

This code I have from internet but does not work

Comment: Please edit your question instead of writing an answer.

Comment: Sorry not familiar with Stack Overflow